# jquery replace div content with jsp file content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

i am trying to replace div content with jsp file content, but i get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL" error.

if the jsp file has one line it's working fine, but this issue happened when the jsp had multi lines.

test.jsp file:

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#content").html("<jsp:include page='dashboard.jsp'></jsp:include>");
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="content">123</div>
</body>
</html>
```

dashboard.jsp file:

```
<div id='test'>
    dashboard
</div>
```

Comment: try this : `$("#content").html('<jsp:include page="dashboard.jsp"></jsp:include>');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Try this code. i have use load function in jquery.

html page

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(){
           $('#selectedTarget').load('try.jsp');
       });
    </script>   
</head>
 <body>
    <div id="selectedTarget">
        Existing content.
    </div>
    <div>
        Existing content.
    </div>
</body>
```

try.jsp page(i don't know jsp so i just wrote below line in jsp file)

hi this is try